# Fastest way to retrieve data in an area based on xy coordinates?

Tags: c#, algorithms

So I have an unsorted data set with x and y float coordinates as keys. The data is in a txt file. It looks like this:

x,y,data;

x2,y2,data2;

etc

I need to retrieve all data in a specific rectangular area multiple times with different areas each time. What would be the fastest algorithm to do this. (I'm working in C#)

My current solution looks like this:

1. Create a sorted dictionary(dic1) with X key and y values
2. Create a sorted dictionary(dic2) with y key and data values
3. Create a list(list1) and add all X in dic1 that are between max-X and min-X(based on the area wanted)
4. Create another list(list2) and for each item in list1, if the item has a y between max-Y and min-Y (based on the area wanted) then add to list2.
5. List2 is our set of points in the target area

Anything faster?

Comment: what performance problems are you having now ?

Comment: It is not clear to me at all how that would work.    How would adding Y from dic 2 give you an area?    That would be minX < x  < maxX  OR minY < y < maxY.   The is like a cross?  Is that really your area?

Comment: What meta information do you have about the points? Do you know their order forms the right shape or is the order random and you have to construct the shape?  Do you know how many points there will be or are there variable numbers of points?

Comment: I don't understand why dic2 is needed at all.  After step 3 you have a list of points all of which are in range for the x coordinate.  Why not simply *not* add points to that list if the y coordinate of the point is out of range?

Comment: Also: sorting the points (twice) requires examining every point.  If you're going to examine every point, then why sort at all?  **Just examine every point and discard the ones that are out of range**. What does sorting buy you?

Comment: How many points do you have ? How many points usually go into the area-result set? Are all point in memory or in a sql databse?

Comment: @Newtopian preemptive thinking/no problems

Comment: @Paparazzi it's not an OR, it's an AND. If minX < x < maxX then x is part of list 1. If minY < y < maxY then y is part of list 2. List 2 is our target points within the area...

Comment: @enderland no meta info/no order/variable numbers.

Comment: @EricLippert The data first has to be modeled from a txt file to be understood by the program. The model I used are the 2 dictionary which in theory should allow fast check of both x and y. Step 1-2 are modeling, step 3-4 are querying/solving. Sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: @k3b Number of points are variable. Points are in a txt file (not 100% accurate but lets say they are to avoid unnecessary details)

Comment: @Paparazzi False. Assume we have minX,minY = 2 and maxX,maxY = 3. Also assume we have point (2.5, 4).  Now lets run the algorithm: step 3: 2 < 2.5 < 3, therefore we add the point to list1. Move to Step 4: 2<4 but 4>3 so the point is not added to list2. This is the same thing as minX < x < maxX AND Y < y < maxY. If you would use a OR, the data would be added to list2.

Comment: Assume I don't care.  Poorly executed  question.  Go forth and Profit.

Comment: @user2997154 New user telling me to get out.  Go forth Conker and Profit.

Comment: @Paparazzi I'm sorry I overreacted to your condescending tone. I see that step 4 in my original question could be confusing and I understand why you thought that it was an OR. Hopefully the edit is clearer. Sorry for this.

Comment: @user2997154 do not feel bad; stackoverflow is a very useful resource, so learning how to properly ask questions will pay out greatly on the long run.  With a properly formulated question you could have gotten a good answer a lot sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [Spatial index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database).

In your case, basic [grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_(spatial_index)) or [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) should be enough.